# How can I return image and text in one request

Tags: php, yii

I need to return two attributes - text and image in one api request. How can I do this?

Comment: your API, some one elses? code? really do you think this is answerable?

Comment: Please, clarify your question!

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why not send the URL to the image like so: `json_encode(array('text => 'Foo', 'image' => 'URL to image'))`

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kindly take a look around and see how to ask a proper, valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Return the text and the path to the file on the server

2) If the file is in a protected folder, then use two requests, one for the text, the second for the image

Sample:

```
         $name = './img/ok.png';
         $fp = fopen($name, 'rb');
         header("Content-Type: image/png");
         header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name)); 
         fpassthru($fp);
```

Comment: There is a third, the image can be returned as base64_encoded data in a JSON response along with text.  Personally I would just return the URL to the image.